# How to send data from AWS IoT to Mysql database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-iot

I am working on AWS IoT first time. I have found that AWS IoT has the functionality to send data to AWS DynamoDB or AWS Lambda. Is there any way to send these data from AWS IoT device to MySql or any other relational database system? If possible, how can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly, as there is no [AWS IoT Action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-rule-actions.html) for RDS or relational databases, but your Lambda action can capture the event and save to the database.

Comment: Could you please provide me any tutorial link from where I can learn this. Thanks again. @Julio_AWS_DevRel